# How to find certain informations in unstructured text

Tags: information-retrieval

i want to implement an application to analyze text. It should check the text for information that I define, e.g. a product announcement, a comment about someone or something, ....
The important text then just needs to be extracted without changing anything.

What should I look at to aquire the knowledge to do that? Can you recoment a method/algorithm to do that?

Thanks for the help 
AVL

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how smart your analyzer has to be.

The simplest approach would be to search for a keyword, perhaps by regular expressions.

One could also think of using some statistical text analysis like spam filters do (see e. g. http://bogofilter.org/ or http://nasauber.de/opensource/b8/) to distinguish ham from spam. One could create a database with "learned" texts typical for one topic and then calculate the "spamminess", saying the probability that the text is about that topic for each database. This will probably work fine, but it's alot of work to write the code doing it.